# How to compare two images in Elixir

Tags: image, image-processing, erlang, elixir

I have two images in base64 form and I want to compare both images before save to avoid duplicate images.

I try to compare both images like string `image1_base64 != image2_base64` it works for some images but it skips all those images which are minor changed from the previous image.

I want to skip only identical images.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, you have 2 images with minor changes that have the same base64 representation (`image1_base64 == image2_base64` returns `true`)?

Comment: Yes, because there is only date difference on the images.

Comment: By date difference you mean the created/modified date/time of the file on the filesystem?

Comment: Not created/modified date/time. I have date/time over the image.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "base64 form"? How are you getting/generating those? You cannot have 2 non-identical images convert to the same base64 value.

Comment: Can you provide example of two images?

Comment: I'd suggest you drop out to a command shell and do a binary comparison.  Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118403/comparing-binary-files

Comment: It's not solvable with default Elxir means. You need to investigate in neural networks and computer vision topics.