# Two copies of the same files register as having numerous differences

Tags: macos, terminal, diff

When using the diff command in Terminal to compare the original folder on my SSD, and the backup newly created on a HDD, numerous files are listed as "Binary Files .... differ," but to my observation, the file are all identical. What is going on, was there an error in copying?

Comment: In what way did you observe them to be identical? It's hard to compare binary files by eye. You might try using a tool meant for comparing binary files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118403/how-to-compare-binary-files-to-check-if-they-are-the-same

Comment: @EllenSpertus for example, it listed two short text files as having differences, but checking the files themselves, the text is identical. Why would this happen?

Comment: What did you check their text with? Some tools don't display binary data well.

Comment: It might also be that your command only compares creation times. Did you try `cmp` on the files?