# How to compare two PDF files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, pdf, comparison

I am trying to compare two PDF files using UTF-8, but I get the error "Invalid encoding" when I execute the code below:

```
 encoding = 'utf-8'
 base_path = set_up
 tear_down do
   f1 = File.read("#{TMP_DIR}/#{current_file_name}", encoding: encoding)
   f2 = File.read("#{base_path}/#{expected_file_name}", encoding: encoding)
   expect(f1).to eql f2
 end
```

I tried to use:

```
f1.force_encoding("UTF-8")
f2.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

I tried this too:

```
f1.force_encoding("BINARY")
```

but, I get another error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

Comment: Personally I'd do this using a command-line tool, like `diff`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118413/128421. It's easy, fast, and sidesteps the encoding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing the file as strings I would just compare the files' MD5 hash:

```
require 'digest'

tear_down do
  md5_1 = Digest::MD5.file("#{TMP_DIR}/#{current_file_name}")
  md5_2 = Digest::MD5.file("#{base_path}/#{expected_file_name}")

  expect(md5_1).to eql md5_2
end
```

Comment: Thank you spickermann.
But i have this diff with your code :

`RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: 
expected: #<Digest::MD5: 413bf62b1d4ac74a4ba03d263e2672aa>
     got: #<Digest::MD5: 0937bd7a200fb2dd983e1f5894b8addc>
`
Does this method compare text and format?

Comment: This method compares on a binary level - every single bit needs to be the same. Basically like your method did but yours translated the binary to a string text before comparing every single character (text and all formating in the file).

Comment: Thx spickermann. So what is the solution ? 
If I understand correctly, should I transform the files into binary before comparing them?

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to compare. Do the files need to be identical or do they just need to include the same text?

Comment: I have to compare that the content is the same in the 2 pdf files.

is this code did the same that yours ?

  ```
  base_path = set_up
  tear_down do

    md5_1 = `cat "#{TMP_DIR}/#{current_file_name}" | grep -a -v "/CreationDate" | md5sum`.strip
    md5_2  = `cat "#{base_path}/#{expected_file_name}" | grep -a -v "/CreationDate" | md5sum`.strip

    expect(md5_1).to eql md5_2
 ```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @spickermann for your help
this working fine for me after deleting the diff "CreationDate" between the 2 pdf files:

```
base_path = set_up
tear_down do
  md5_1 = `cat "#{TMP_DIR}/#{current_file_name}" | grep -a -v "/CreationDate" | md5sum`.strip
  md5_2  = `cat "#{base_path}/#{expected_file_name}" | grep -a -v "/CreationDate" | md5sum`.strip
  expect(md5_1).to eql md5_2
end
```